# is there any way to get position of the RECT in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to know is there any way I can have the position of the Rect I create and stored in variable name "rect" in pygame

Answer (score 1):

A [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object has a lot of virtual attributes:

> The Rect object has several virtual attributes which can be used to move and align the Rect:
>
> ```
> x,y
> top, left, bottom, right
> topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
> midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
> center, centerx, centery
> size, width, height
> w,h
> ```

The top left position of the `pygame.Rect` object can be get and set with the `x` and `y` attribute:

```py
rect = pygame.Rect(10, 20, 5, 5)
print(rect.x, rect.y)
```